# Filter an array of objects to only have the last occurrence of that object with the same certain property

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How would you filter an array of objects to only have the last occurrence of that object with the same prop of foo? I.e

given:

```
[
{foo:1,id:1},
{foo:1,id:2},
{foo:2,id:3}
]
```

I want this back:

```
[
{foo:1,id:2},
{foo:2,id:3}
```

I'm using es6 so I can start from here:

```
 this.data.filter((item,index,self)=> {
     return self.findIndex(o => o.foo === item.foo);
    })
```

Comment: Create a map by `foo`'s value

Answer (score 5):

```
var index = {};
var data = [{foo:1,id:1},{foo:1,id:2},{foo:2,id:3}];

data.forEach(item => index[item.foo] = item);

index[1];
// {foo:1,id:2}

Object.values(index)
// [{foo:1,id:2},{foo:2,id:3}]
```

Comment: This is genius, to overwrite the value!

Answer (score 2):

Create a map by `foo`'s value

```
var map = {};
var arr = [
  {foo:1,id:1},
  {foo:1,id:2},
  {foo:2,id:3}
];
arr.forEach( function(item){
  map[ item.foo ] = item;
});
```

and now finally just get the map's values

```
var finalArray = Object.keys( map ).map( function(key){
  return map[key];
});
```

Comment: Note that you're using word _map_ to refer to object. Confusing with `Map` in ES6.

Comment: @Tushar that is true, but not sure why would it be confusing though.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [{foo:1, id:1}, {foo:1, id:2}, {foo:2, id:3}, {foo:2, id:4}, {foo:2, id:5}, {foo:3, id:6}],
    e = {};
    arr.forEach(v => e[v.foo] = v.id);
    var res = Object.keys(e).map(v => arr.find(c => c.id == e[v]));
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

In just O(n) time you can achieve this job by the `.rightReduce()`
functionality with an initial value tuple holding both the result and a hash.

```js
function lastWithProp(a,p){
  return a.reduceRight((r,o) => r[1][p+o[p]] ? r : (r[1][p+o[p]] = true, r[0].push(o),r), [[],{}])[0];
}

var data = [{foo:1,id:1},{foo:1,id:2},{foo:2,id:3}],
result   = lastWithProp(data,"foo");
console.log(result);
```

The `.rightReduce()` initial value (the `r` argument of the callback) is a tuple (a double/triple/quadruple... group of different type of data zipped together) like `[[],{}]` in this case. `r[0]` holds the result as it forms  through the iterations of `.rightReduce()` and `r[1]` holds a hash map of the met objects property value keystring if never met before. So the first time we meet `{foo:1,...}` we mark it in the hash (`r[1]`) like `"foo1" = true` (`r[1][p+o[p]] = true`). So on...

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have to play with this to understand it.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper I added some explanation to my answer may be it can help.

Comment: how fast is it compared to @Tomalak's one?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper OK @Tomalak's code is actually doing the same thing in an imperative fashion while this one is more functional. Performance wise  it will all boil down to `.forEach()` vs `.rightReduce()` and from my experience `.rightReduce()` is faster in most of the engines. However if Tomalak's code is modified to run with a `while` loop, then for sure it will be the winner. For me `.forEach()` is a very needless tool in functional JS and in the imperative JS, you never ever need it since it's nothing but a drag.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Yes totally.. imperative paradigm involves your instructions to directly access and change variables defined here or there, iterations are done by a `for` or `while` loop... It's the abacus of CS. While in pure functional languages (like Haskell etc) you don't even have a `for` or `while` loop. Everything is handled by self contained functions etc... From this point, i guess functional programming paradigm seems like the calculus of CS: